# Get the ID of a selected value from a dropdown selectbox using Laravel 5.1

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.1, html-select, laravel-routing, laravel-blade

I've been on this for a while, what I want to do is to get the id of the selected value from a select box. Using this snippet, it doesn't  get the id and I wonder why. I'm confused what what could be wrong

This code is to get the id of the selected value:

```
private static function compareCompany(ProductRequest $productRequest){
            $companyPicked = $productRequest->companyname;
            $listedCompanies = Company::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
            $companies = new Company;
            if($companies->user_id === Auth::user()->id)
            {   
                foreach($listedCompanies as $company) {
                    if($company->companyname === $companyPicked)
                    {
                        return $company->id;
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
```

This is to create a new product using the id returned for a company

```
public function store(ProductRequest $productRequest)
    {
       $product = new Product;
        $company = new Company;
       if($productRequest->isMethod('post')){

       $product->user_id     = Auth::user()->id;
       $product->company_id  = $this->compareCompany($productRequest);
       $product->companyname = $productRequest->companyname;
       $product->productname = $productRequest->productname;

       $product->save();
       return redirect()->route('companyindex')->with('message', 'Your question has been posted.');
       }else{
            return redirect('company-create')->withErrors($productRequest)->withInput();
        }
    }
```

THis is the view:

```
<p>{!! Form::select('companyname', array('' => 'Select a Company') + $listCompanies) !!} </p>
```

THis is the code used in binding the returned value to the view:

```
public function create()
    {

      $listCompanies = Company::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('companyname', 'desc')->lists('companyname', 'companyname')->toArray();
        return view('product.create')
        ->with('listCompanies', $listCompanies);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem is with your `compareCompany` method. There are a couple of issues there.

Here's your code (cleaned up a bit):

```
private static function compareCompany(ProductRequest $productRequest)
{
    $companyPicked = $productRequest->companyname;

    $listedCompanies = Company::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);

    $companies = new Company;

    if($companies->user_id === Auth::user()->id)
    {   
        foreach($listedCompanies as $company) {
            if($company->companyname === $companyPicked)
            {
                return $company->id;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

And here are the issues:

1. `$listedCompanies = Company::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);`

   This statement doesn't actually produce a list of companies. You need to add `->get()` at the end, like this:

`$listedCompanies = Company::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();`

2. `$companies = new Company;`

   This creates a new, uninitialized instance of the `Company` model. On the next line you go on to check the `user_id` property of that instance, but it's not set to anything because it's brand new. So the first `if()` statement always fails. It's not clear what you're trying to do here, so I'm not sure how to fix this one. My guess is that you're trying to filter out only the companies that belong to the current user, but you've already done that with your `Company::where(...)->get()`, so this is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate your support. What I want to do I suppose it's to be simple and straight forward. Overall, what i want to achieve is to get the item selected from the blade file, with the hidden file and send it to the server side. This function "compareCompany" is to be used to compare if the company actually exist for the user, and get the id of the company. That is why I instantiated the company class. Once the id is returned, that is what should be stored as the company id. Please help out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change `->lists('companyname', 'companyname')` to `->lists('companyname', 'id')`

It will return the `id` of the table of `Company` model.